# xsl: how to add a popup modal

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add a popup modal found on W3schools.com (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) to each `<line>`. When a user clicks on any `<line>`, the corresponding `<title>`, the entire `<description>` and `<footer>` should popup. My xml look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <title>Header1</title>
        <description>
            <p>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 2 of description of item 1.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 1.
                </line>
            </p>
        </description>
        <footer>Footer1</footer>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Header2</title>
        <description>
            <p>
                <line>
                    This is line 1 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                     This is line 2 of description of item 2.
                </line>
                <line>
                    This is line 3 of description of item 2.
                </line>
            </p>
        </description>
        <footer>Footer2</footer>
    </item>
</items>
```

If I add the `<div id="myModal" class="modal">` and `<script>` in my xsl, the xsl doesn't produce the output.

Here is my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item/title"/>
             <script>
               function para() {
               // Get the modal
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

                // Get the button that opens the modal
                var p = document.getElementById("myBtn");

                // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
                p.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                 }

                // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
                 span.onclick = function() {
                  modal.style.display = "none";
                }

                // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
                 window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                 }
               }
             }
       </script>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
   <p onclick="para()" id="myBtn">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <span class="close">&times;</span>
       <h2>Modal Header</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <p>text in the Modal</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php


    $xml = new DOMDocument;
    // Load XML file
    $xml->load('test.xml');


    // Load XSL file
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('test.xsl');

    // Configure the transformer
    $xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor;

    // Attach the xsl rules
    $xsltProcessor->importStyleSheet($xsl);


    echo $xsltProcessor->transformToXML($xml);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: write a function within your script tag and then just use the `onclick=` attribute button ui element to call that method.  As it is you are creating broken HTML with multiple elements with the same ID and you are creating duplicate script tags.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, I created a function and added onclick (see above). The function and onclick work. However, the xsl still doesn't produce any output if I add myModal div.

Comment: @SteveDEU Perhaps you didn't read Steps 2 and 3 of w3schools' tutorial?

Comment: I added the script and style in the head of html. The problem is <xsl:apply-templates/> doesn't produce any results with <div id="myModal" class="modal"> below it.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, you are putting `div` elements into a `p` element, that is not allowed content of a `p` element, neither in HTML 4 nor in HTML5. So depending on how you use XSLT the generated HTML might not even have the structure you intend to create there. Furthermore you should create a minimal but complete sample to demonstrate the issue you have, if you need script and CSS in your HTML to emulate a modal dialogue then you need to include it. I would suggest to first create static HTML that does what you want and then to create the XSLT to generate that HTML.

Comment: My bad. I added xsl, xml, and php.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hi Martin, my actual xml has a slightly different structure, and I cannot figure out how your solution would apply to the actual xml. Sorry, but would you help me with the modified xml above. Please also read the modified question. I spent hours but no luck. Please help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen What if <description> contains multiple <p>s? How can I display the corresponding <p> in the popup modal? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinHonnen never mind, I figured it out. Thank you so much. You made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use is for a single modal dialogue, you would need to extend it to allow it to work with various modal dialogues, here is a simple Javascript/HTML/CSS combo to do that:

```js
var modals = {
  currentModal : null,
  openModal : function(id) {
    this.currentModal = document.getElementById(id);
    this.currentModal.style.display = 'block';
  },
  close : function() {
    if (this.currentModal != null) {
      this.currentModal.style.display = 'none';
      this.currentModal = null;
    }
  }
}


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of a modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modals.currentModal) {
        modals.close();
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal 1 -->
<button onclick="modals.openModal('modal1');">Open Modal 1</button>

<!-- The Modal 1 -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content  1-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="modals.close();">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 1..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal 2 -->
<button onclick="modals.openModal('modal2');">Open Modal 2</button>

<!-- The Modal 2 -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content  2-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="modals.close();">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal 2..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now you would need to ensure your XSLT generates that structure, here is a complete stylesheet that does that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.1" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
                <style>
     /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }                   
                </style>
                <script>
     var modals = {
      currentModal : null,
      openModal : function(id) {
        this.currentModal = document.getElementById(id);
        this.currentModal.style.display = 'block';
      },
      close : function() {
        if (this.currentModal != null) {
          this.currentModal.style.display = 'none';
          this.currentModal = null;
        }
      }
    }


    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of a modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modals.currentModal) {
            modals.close();
        }
    }                 
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item" mode="dialogue"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item">
        <p onclick="modals.openModal('modal{position()}');">
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item" mode="dialogue">
      <xsl:comment>The Modal <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:comment>
      <div id="modal{position()}" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" onclick="modals.close();">&#215;</span>
          <section>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/title" mode="dialogue">
      <h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
      </h2>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/description" mode="dialogue">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/footer" mode="dialogue">
      <h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
      </h3>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example online at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017091201.xml. As you seem to want to run the XSLT server-side with PHP and only generate part of the HTML with XSLT you will obviously need to adapt that.

As for your adapted input XML sample, it is not even well-formed so no way you have tried hours. You will have to find a way to represent the dialogue content in HTML first, then you can simply write the templates to create that structure. Here is an attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.1" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
                <style>
     /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }                   
                </style>
                <script>
     var modals = {
      currentModal : null,
      openModal : function(id) {
        this.currentModal = document.getElementById(id);
        this.currentModal.style.display = 'block';
      },
      close : function() {
        if (this.currentModal != null) {
          this.currentModal.style.display = 'none';
          this.currentModal = null;
        }
      }
    }


    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of a modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modals.currentModal) {
            modals.close();
        }
    }                 
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Test</h1>
                <ul>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item"/>
                </ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item//line" mode="dialogue"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          <ul>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".//line"/>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item//line">
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
           <xsl:number level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <li onclick="modals.openModal('modal{$pos}');">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item//line" mode="dialogue">
      <xsl:comment>The Modal <xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:comment>
      <div id="modal{position()}" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" onclick="modals.close();">&#215;</span>
          <section>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item" mode="dialogue-content"/>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/title" mode="dialogue-content">
      <h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
      </h2>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/description" mode="dialogue-content">
      <section>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue-content"/>
      </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item//line" mode="dialogue-content">
       <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue-content"/>
       </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items/item/footer" mode="dialogue-content">
      <h3>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="dialogue"/>
      </h3>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017091301.xml.

Comment: Wow! great. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Hi Martin, my actual xml has a slightly different structure, and I cannot figure out how your solution would apply to the actual xml. Sorry, but would you help me with the modified xml above. Please also read the modified question. I spent hours but no luck. Please help.

Comment: @SteveDEU, I have adapted the example for the last time, in the future make sure you have a clear problem description and separation of concerns (XSLT or HTML).